# What does "slip about at all" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Serenity (2005)*, Malcolm and Simon hates Alliance:

> Malcolm: Put this crew together with the promise of work, which the
> Alliance makes harder every year.
>
> Simon: Come a day there won't be room for naughty men like us to **slip
> about at all**.

What does "slip about at all" mean?

Comment: You should note that this show uses an invented slang that is a mixture of 1870s wild west, Mandarin Chinese, and Science fiction.  Much of the dialogue (like "come a day", "naughty men" or "slip about") is "unnatural" for a speaker in the 2020s.

Comment: @JamesK "Naughty men" seems like a reasonable way for criminals to jokingly downplay the severity of their crimes when talking amongst themselves, by alluding to the more commonly-used "naughty boys" and implicitly comparing their crimes to childhood hijinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There will no longer be room to perform illegal actions.

In the context of the show, the crew of the spaceship Serenity are a group of smugglers, thieves, and political dissidents that would like to avoid governmental oversight from the Alliance so that they can continue to perform their illegal activities.

So, in this context, "slip about" means to sneak around and perform criminal activities. The words "At all" is part of the phrase "there won't be room at all", which has the noun phrase "naughty men like us" and the verb "slip about" injected into the middle of it.

Comment: It might be worth adding that  "[not] at all" means "not even slightly".